# How do I fix a C++03 double angle bracket template syntax error in Google OR-Tools?

Tags: c++, c++11, or-tools

I'm trying to build a [Google OR-Tools](https://github.com/google/or-tools) example on OSX 10.11.3

When I run:

```
g++  -I../include/ -L../lib -lortools -Wno-c++11-extensions nqueens2.cc

In file included from nqueens2.cc:25:
In file included from ../include/constraint_solver/constraint_solver.h:65:
In file included from ../include/base/hash.h:19:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ext/hash_map:212:5: warning: Use of the header <ext/hash_map> is deprecated.  Migrate to <unordered_map> [-W#warnings]
#   warning Use of the header <ext/hash_map> is deprecated.  Migrate to <unordered_map>
    ^
In file included from nqueens2.cc:25:
In file included from ../include/constraint_solver/constraint_solver.h:65:
In file included from ../include/base/hash.h:20:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ext/hash_set:205:5: warning: Use of the header <ext/hash_set> is deprecated.  Migrate to <unordered_set> [-W#warnings]
#   warning Use of the header <ext/hash_set> is deprecated.  Migrate to <unordered_set>
    ^
In file included from nqueens2.cc:25:
In file included from ../include/constraint_solver/constraint_solver.h:65:
../include/base/hash.h:184:31: error: expected expression
struct hash<std::array<T, N>> {
                              ^
../include/base/hash.h:201:2: error: expected a type
};
 ^
2 warnings and 2 errors generated.
```

I think the problem is that the compiler is including `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ext/hash_map` when I want it to include it from `../include`.

The error causing code is below from `../include/base/hash.h` (which comes with Google OR-Tools):

```
183 template <class T, std::size_t N>
184 struct hash<std::array<T, N>> {
185  public:
186   size_t operator()(const std::array<T, N>& t) const {
187     uint64 current = 71;
188     for (int index = 0; index < N; ++index) {
189       const T& elem = t[index];
190       const uint64 new_hash = hash<T>()(elem);
191       current = operations_research::Hash64NumWithSeed(current, new_hash);
192     }
193     return current;
194   }
195   // Less than operator for MSVC.
196   bool operator()(const std::array<T, N>& a, const std::array<T, N>& b) const {
197     return a < b;
198   }
199   static const size_t bucket_size = 4;  // These are required by MSVC
200   static const size_t min_buckets = 8;  // 4 and 8 are defaults.
201 };
202 #endif  // STLPORT
203 }  // namespace HASH_NAMESPACE
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: The old g++ compiler did not allow for two `>` in a row for a template declaration because it appeared as the `>>` operator. So, when your code is looking at the struct declaration, it sees a `{` brace instead of a expression for the `>>` operator. This was changed in the later c++ standards and g++ changed accordingly.

Comment: @callyalater many thanks -- let me try that

Comment: @callyalater that worked

Comment: Sure thing! Do you want me to post that as an answer?

Comment: would appreciate it -- and I think if you have better ideas of a title

Comment: Maybe change the title to something relating to C++03 double angle bracket template syntax...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old g++ compiler did not allow for two `>` in a row for a template declaration because it appeared as the `>>` operator. So, when your code is looking at the struct declaration, it sees a `{` brace instead of a expression for the `>>` operator. This was changed in the later c++ standards and g++ changed accordingly.

The C++03 compiler mandated that the `>>` be interpreted as a right shift operator. This was changed in the C++0x standard.

Answer (score 1):

I hate specifying includes with a directory path in source code, but it might solve the problem: `#include "../include/hash_map`

Comment: many thanks for your post -- I think the problem was that my g++ compiler was erroring out on the template definition >> which should be > > as a previous commenter specified. Thanks